# Can Perl6 cmp two strings case insensitively?

Tags: raku

I am doing a sort and would like to control the cmp of alpha values to be case insensitive (viz. https://perl6.org/archive/rfc/143.html).

Is there some :i adverb for this, perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by *"alpha values"*? See the unicode foldcase [`fc`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/fc) routine

Comment: i think you should have a look at "coll" and "collate". They are documented, but I don't have enough time to write a proper answer right now.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on coll - by 'alpha values' I mean to compare two English words consisting of letters from the English alphabet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl 6 doesn't currently have that as an option, but it is a very mutable language so let's add it.

Since the existing `proto` doesn't allow named values we have to add a new one, or write an `only` sub.
(That is you can just use the `multi` below except with an optional `only` instead.)

This only applies lexically, so if you write this you may want to mark the `proto`/`only` sub as being exportable depending on what you are doing.

```perl6
proto sub infix:<leg> ( \a, \b, *% ){*}

multi sub infix:<leg> ( \a, \b, :ignore-case(:$i) ){
  $i

  ?? &CORE::infix:<leg>( fc(a) , fc(b) )
  !! &CORE::infix:<leg>(    a  ,    b  )
}
```

```perl6
say 'a' leg 'A';     # More
say 'a' leg 'A' :i;  # Same
say 'a' leg 'A' :!i; # More

say 'a' leg 'A' :ignore-case; # Same
```

Note that `:$i` is short for `:i( $i )` so the two named parameters could have been written as:
`:ignore-case( :i( $i ) )`

Also I used the sub form of `fc()` rather than the method form `.fc` because it allows the native form of strings to be used without causing autoboxing.

Comment: thanks @brad - I always learn a massive amount when I study your replies - (i) FWIW personally I prefer the $ sigil over \ maybe due to years of perl5 also (ii) I wonder whether samewith may be applicable in the example...?

Comment: @p6steve I used `\a` after looking at `&infix:<leg>».candidates».signature».say` and noticing the first candidate has that. No it can't use `samewith` or similars because the `proto` has hidden them.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a "dictionary" sort order, @timotimo is on the right track when they suggest `collate` and `coll` for sorting.

Use `collate()` on anything listy to sort it.  Use `coll` as an infix operator in case you need a custom sort.

```
$ perl6
To exit tyype 'exit' or '^D'
> <a Zp zo zz ab 9 09 91 90>.collate();
(09 9 90 91 a ab zo Zp zz)
> <a Zp zo zz ab 9 09 91 90>.sort: * coll *;
(09 9 90 91 a ab zo Zp zz)
```

Comment: this is probably the best fit for me - no need to redefine the language and is clear what the intent of the collate function is...

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a code block to sort. If the arity of the block is one, it works on both elements when doing the comparison. Here's an example showing the 'fc' from the previous answer.

```
> my @a = <alpha BETA gamma DELTA>;
[alpha BETA gamma DELTA]
> @a.sort
(BETA DELTA alpha gamma)
> @a.sort(*.fc)
(alpha BETA DELTA gamma)
```

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/traps#Case-insensitive_comparison_of_strings)

> In order to do case-insensitive comparison, you can use `.fc`
>   (fold-case). The problem is that people tend to use `.lc` or `.uc`, and it
>   does seem to work within the ASCII range, but fails on other
>   characters. This is not just a Perl 6 trap, the same applies to other
>   languages.

For example:

```
say ‘groß’.fc eq ‘GROSS’.fc; # ← RIGHT; True
```

If you are working with regexes, then there is no need to use `.fc` and you can use `:i` (`:ignorecase`) adverb instead.

Comment: As a German speaker, I would expect 'groß’.fc to be equal to ‘GROSS'.fc in the interpretation that s == S and thus ß == ss == SS ... perhaps this is what the unicode definers had in mind?

Comment: But I just tried 'ü'.fc eq 'ue'.fc #False - so not very consistent then...